# yii2 Запрос с пересчетом валют

Tags: php, yii2

Делаю фильтр для объявлений. Есть такой пункт, как выбор в какой валюте выводить суммы.

Каким образом можно в фильтре пересчитать и вывести результат с пересчитанными значениями? То есть курсы у меня есть, пересчитывать знаю как. Вопрос можно ли запрос такого типа сделать ?

```
if($this->course_type == Course::CONST_EUR){
      $query->andFilterWhere(['object.price' * $course_value]);
}
```

Выдает ошибку 'Operator `'0' requires two operand` , да и не думаю что фильтр может пересчитывать и менять выводимые данные.

Но идей пока нету, подскажите как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Yii2 сильно не изучал, но вот в данном случае вы фразу `object.price` умножаете на какое-то значение `$course_value` (не надо так). А вам надо сделать в таком виде: `['object.price' => $price * $rate]`, то есть, насколько я понимаю, колонка `price` в таблице `object` должна быть равна запрошенной цене, умноженной на курс выбранной валюты.

Comment: Суть вопроса не в том. Как пересчитать я знаю. Есть таблица с валютами, и курс. В базе все значения usd по дефолту. Проблема в том, как именно прописать эту арифметическую операцию в фильтре так, чтобы оно в представлении выводило уже не значение с базы, а пересчитанное

Comment: Вам описали вашу ошибку (умножение строки на нечто), как вы думаете какой там может быть результат? Метод "andFilterWhere" добавляет значение в секцию "WHERE" вашего запроса, опять же, что вы в итоге получаете в секции которая отвечает за фильтрацию в таблице, а не за модификацию. Как вариант можете в `select` написать ваше умножение  'SELECT object.price * 2.4 as price ...'

Comment: Покажите, что до этого вызывается в `$query`

Comment: В `$query` еще много фильтров типа - `$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'type_flat.id',$this->type_house]);` ,  `$query->andFilterWhere(['between', 'object.price', $this->price_from != null ? $this->price_from : 0, $this->price_to != null ? $this->price_to : $max_price]);
` и т.д.

Comment: Вот такое условие пересчитывает `$query->select("(object.price * $var) AS price");` .. Но проблема в том что только этот запрос и выполняется, т.е. ничего не выводит кроме цены. Нужно бы что-то типа andWhere , только andSelect , бред.. но что-то в этом роде есть ?

Comment: @VladShkuta `$query->select("(object.price * $var) AS price, *");` или как ниже написали, перечислить все столбцы

Comment: _Но проблема в том что только этот запрос и выполняется_ - только этот столбец выбирается. Советую потренироваться/разобраться в написании нативных sql запросов, будет проще

Answer (score 0):

В зависимости от того, каким образом у вас строится запрос, в конструкторе нужно изменить список выводимых полей, подменив `price` приблизительно таким образом:

```
$query->select("id, name, ..., (price * $rate) as price");
```

Comment: Запрос у меня строится так - по модели поиска проходит, и прибавляет к запросу нужные условия - `SELECT ... WHERE.... OR (`object`.`type_id`=7)) AND (`object_type`.`parent_id`=1)) AND (`object`.`type_id`=3)) AND (`commission_value`='0')` . По такой схеме можно только прописать этот `$query-select()` в самом начале, где только формируется запрос ?

Comment: @VladShkuta его можно написать где угодно до выполнения запроса, он переопределит SELECT

Comment: @VladShkuta, Если `select` не был задан, то, скорее всего, по умолчанию он выведет все возможные поля из всех таблиц, участвующих в запросе.

Comment: Что-то делаю не так.. Самая первая строка, где создается запрос `$query = ObjectModel::find()` . Пишу так - `$query = ObjectModel::find()->select("(price * 5) AS price, *");` .. Ошибка, дальше запрос не идет.

Comment: Запрос точнее идет дальше, но dataProvider не передает данные в представление, только значение price

Comment: Если, к примеру вот такой запрос сначала делать - `$query = ObjectModel::find()->select(["(price * 5) AS price, course_id"]);` передаст 2 значения в dataProvider

Answer (score 0):

Все оказалось проще, кому надо.
Есть такой метод как `addSelect` 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#addSelect()-detail
Вставляем в любом месте

```
$query->addSelect(["object.*, round(price * $course_usd->course) AS price"]);
```